# what kind of faucet is this and how do I take off handle?

Tags: faucet, kitchen-sink

The handle is loose (a bit wiggly) and I want to take it off to figure out how to tighten it.  Problem is I can't figure out how to take it off...

[image]
[image]

My guess is it is from mid to late 2000s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should find a set screw under the small colored plug.

[image]

Comment: Are you suggesting to detach the small colored plug?  Is there a method you would suggest that would not break the plug (and allow it to be reattached later)?

Comment: @BigRon - Yes. The plug is simply pressed into the hole used to access the set screw. Usually it can be simply picked out. If it is being hard to get out one can carefully pry it out from the edge with a sharp knife blade. Best to plug the sink drains first in case the plug pops out into the sink.

Comment: Great explanation and follow up tip.

Comment: Thanks.  Your answer came before @Randy's, which is why I've chosen it.  My problem now is that none of my allen wrenches seem to fit.  2.5mm is too small; 3mm is too big.  I think it might be 7/64" which is a wrench I am going to have to go buy somewhere.

Comment: You may want to consider something [like this tool set](http://www.amazon.com/Stanley-STHT71839-Folding-Metric-2-Pack/dp/B00D4C18CU/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1421416189&sr=8-3&keywords=allen+wrenches) that includes both metric and SAE sizes in a convenient handle holders.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the red/blue plug with your fingernail.  It's just pressed in place.  Beneath is an allen bolt (often 5/32).  I think that's what is loose.  Tighten the bolt, then replace the red/blue plug, and you're done.

Comment: took me three times through to realize i had a smudge on my screen. I wanted to know what an *alien* bold was :)