# How do I get into this kind of faucet to fix a drip?

Tags: faucet, plumbing-fixture

How can I get this thing apart? Using this [question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/57593/what-kind-of-faucet-is-this-and-how-do-i-take-off-handle) I was able to take out a bolt of some sort inside the top from behind the blue/red thing, but the top still doesn't come off.

It's dripping, and I wanted to fix whatever is wrong on the inside.

[image]

Here's a short video showing what I tried:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n_XXLcKhsdE

Comment: Dribble vinegar into the screw hole as well as you can and wait for half an hour or so.  Then try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the manufacturer and google this repair giving the model and manufacturer; you should find information on this repair. Go to the home store and look for a repair kit for this manufacturer. Note that you must turn off the hot and cold supply to this faucet before you release the ring which holds the inner parts in place.

For example I Googled: youtube repair of single handle kitchen faucet and got this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=huxSQljCrIc

Comment: Woa, the handle just pops off in that vid. Mine doesn't. Thanks, I'll go see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

It it has been some time (months or years) since it was last disassembled, parts might be stuck together.

With the screw completely removed, get as close as you can to it and pull the handle upward firmly as a unit (that is, don't work the temperature or volume lever) while gently rocking it back and forth as well as side to side.  It is normal for it to take 15–30 seconds of this to get it to release.

Comment: Video of me trying to get the thing off: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n_XXLcKhsdE

Comment: @Almo:  Yep, that is the retaining nut you took out.  You initially pulled and I thought I saw it lift up toward success just a little bit.  But then you got discouraged.  I think if you continue to wiggle and pull up, it will come.